# Replacing strings of (Hexidecimal) zeros in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I have binary code that have 4 sets of zero strings (00 00 00 00) and also have sets of 3 (00 00 00). I want to get rid of the sets of 4. (replace with nothing.) When I do 00 00 00 00 in "find", it's also effecting the sets of 3 zeros which I don't want to touch. I have "match whole word" selected and tried parentheses and other operands but nothing works. How to you do this?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: By default binary files opened in Notepad++ are not displayed in hex format - what mechanism are you using to view the data this way?

Comment: With standard Text finding `00 00 00 00` does NOT match `00 00 00`.  As @dtmland points out, you seem to have forgotten mentioning some plugin or technique you're using to view/search Hex. Can you please edit that information into your question?

Comment: There is no trick or plugin used. I just selected the HEX from a hex editor and pasted it into notepad as plain text.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a link to your file. I've been learning REGEX and could be of some help to you

Comment: By the way, this is a little urgent for me so I'm constantly checking my emails, waiting for a reply but I didn't get any email about the last 2 comments. Is there a way on this site to get updated via email when I get comments and not just answers? Thanks.

Comment: Prasanna, sure. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35393308/hex.txt

Comment: @ZviTwersky, are you assuming that the highlighted green text is matching your search?  If so, your assumption is incorrect.  Make sure you click "Find Next" a few times to verify your claim.

Comment: heavyd, I didn't think of that - I just saw the green and assumed. Just checked "find next" and yes, it skips the sets of 3. Can you post in an answer (not a comment) so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your screenshot your showing several results highlighted in green.   These highlights are not your search results, they're matching the current selection in the editor.  The search will not actually match `00 00 00` like you claim.